# Break Plot x-axis will not allow me to specify the ticks

Tags: plotting

I have a plot that at large x values it plateaus for while but since it plateaus for so long the important data at small x values is hidden. It is important to me to keep all the data on the plot, so I want to use the resource function plotGrid to combine the plots and insert a zigzag or cut for the Merge Axis option. However, I have two problems. One, I need the indictators to not just appear on the x axis but also in the data itself. Secondly, I want the x axis to be small at both "cuts". Otherwise, there is no point in cutting the data this way if the plot still ends up being really long.

Here is my data and my code thus far:

```
free1 = {0.00000000000000000, 0.00216828031523504, 
   0.00484646756121604, 0.00822958933548484, 0.01261979757959420, 
   0.01850381795962170, 0.02669643491165340, 0.03859926436228570, 
   0.05659300622113340, 0.08425478565477700, 0.12521027395068000, 
   0.28123795256553000, 0.47025649725253800};
free2 = {0.000000000000000000, 0.000221669554150525, 
   0.000498412319663383, 0.000853558926976195, 0.001325691343608660, 
   0.001983408475128010, 0.002961071273079320, 0.004559975786985530, 
   0.007605504571753910, 0.015163263242689500, 0.041651867698633900, 
   0.229888734281491000, 0.438728643203734000};
free3 = {0.0000000000000000000, 0.0000444222892466012, 
   0.0000999362987263996, 0.0001712845888380830, 
   0.0002663590160649210, 0.0003993296882421340, 
   0.0005984167065213870, 0.0009289303414137250, 
   0.0015830479951732800, 0.0034548357171028100, 
   0.0188703005649166000, 0.2238080508940200000, 
   0.4355804107948850000};
free4 = {0.000000000000000000, 0.000442239799344615, 
   0.000993673347855134, 0.001700027274447620, 0.002636340861914330, 
   0.003934443010915280, 0.005847408189475710, 0.008922122490418900, 
   0.014543659571164300, 0.026924419639100600, 0.058335426047750200, 
   0.236976974469341000, 0.442571420759904000};
fracsat1 = {0.000000000000000, 0.133848133848142, 0.301158301158308, 
   0.447876447876455, 0.586872586872590, 0.692406692406701, 
   0.774774774774774, 0.831402831402836, 0.903474903474900, 
   0.916344916344906, 0.957528957528965, 0.990990990990989, 
   1.009009009009010};
fracsat2 = {0.000000000000000, 0.135629709364899, 0.301399354144229, 
   0.452099031216363, 0.589881593110859, 0.691065662002154, 
   0.775026910656617, 0.835306781485459, 0.904198062432726, 
   0.919268030139941, 0.955866523143162, 0.990312163616786, 
   1.009687836383210};
fracsat3 = {0.000000000000000, 0.144750254842004, 0.309887869520897, 
   0.458715596330290, 0.601427115188591, 0.697247706422019, 
   0.780835881753318, 0.841997961264023, 0.909276248725803, 
   0.925586136595322, 0.958205912334360, 0.990825688073398, 
   1.009174311926600};
fracsat4 = {0.000000000000000, 0.077669902912613, 0.223300970873784, 
   0.300970873786397, 0.466019417475678, 0.592233009708739, 
   0.669902912621352, 0.679611650485407, 0.834951456310633, 
   0.805825242718468, 0.932038834951442, 0.990291262135945, 
   1.009708737864060};
nubar3 = {0.0000000000000000, 0.0999551334878079, 0.1998980649754580, 
   0.2998235768733990, 0.3997229866234310, 0.4995807038273900, 
   0.5993656782911300, 0.6990060445346760, 0.7982903081652100, 
   0.8962342290683590, 0.9792426693785860, 0.9982159427442280, 
   0.9990825275858820};
data01 = Transpose[{free4, fracsat1}];
data02 = Transpose[{free4, fracsat2}];
data03 = Transpose[{free4, fracsat3}];
data04 = Transpose[{free4, fracsat4}];
fitdata = Transpose[{free2, nubar3}];
plotGrid = ResourceFunction["PlotGrid"];
plot01 = ListPlot[{data01, data02, data03, data04, fitdata}, 
   Joined -> {False, False, False, False, True}, FrameStyle -> Black, 
   PlotStyle -> Black, 
   PlotMarkers -> {"+", "-", Text[x], "\[FilledSquare]", ""}, 
   PlotRange -> {{0, 0.07}, {0, 1.05}}, PlotRange -> All, 
   ImageSize -> 500];
plot02 = ListPlot[{data01, data02, data03, data04, fitdata}, 
   Joined -> {False, False, False, False, True}, PlotStyle -> Black, 
   PlotMarkers -> {"+", "-", Text[x], "\[FilledSquare]", ""}, 
   PlotRange -> {{0.20, 0.27}, {0, 1.05}}, PlotRange -> All, 
   ImageSize -> 500, Frame -> {{False, False}, {True, False}}];
plot03 = ListPlot[{data01, data02, data03, data04, fitdata}, 
   Joined -> {False, False, False, False, True}, PlotStyle -> Black, 
   PlotMarkers -> {"+", "-", Text[x], "\[FilledSquare]", ""}, 
   PlotRange -> {{0.35, 0.48}, {0, 1.05}}, PlotRange -> All, 
   ImageSize -> 500, Frame -> {{False, False}, {True, False}}];
plotGrid[{{plot01, plot02, plot03}}, ImageSize -> 500, 
 "MergeAxes" -> "Cut", Spacings -> {10, 0}, ItemSize -> {1, {1, 1}}]
```

**UPDATE**
I have been playing around with this plot and here is what I've got so far. Here is what is remaining to fix:

1.I am struggling to get the x axis ticks to be the values I am trying to specify with the option `Ticks`. Why is this? As you can see, the tick labels are running into each other and I'd like for them to be uniform.

2.Also, anyone know how to get the `//` merge indicator in the data itself?

3. Lastly, I would like to make the line for `fitdata` to be smoothly joined. Right now the line is kind of rigid.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Here is my updated script:

```
plot01 = ListPlot[{data01, data02, data03, data04, fitdata}, 
   Joined -> {False, False, False, False, True}, PlotStyle -> Black, 
   PlotMarkers -> {"+", "-", Text[x], "\[FilledSquare]", ""}, 
   AspectRatio -> Full, PlotRange -> {{0, 0.08}, {0, 1.05}}, 
   ImageSize -> 500, Frame -> {{True, True}, {True, False}}, 
   Ticks -> {{0.01, 0.02, 0.03, 0.04, 0.05, 0.06, 0.07}, Automatic}];

plot02 = ListPlot[{data01, data02, data03, data04, fitdata}, 
   Joined -> {False, False, False, False, True}, PlotStyle -> Black, 
   PlotMarkers -> {"+", "-", Text[x], "\[FilledSquare]", ""}, 
   AspectRatio -> Full, PlotRange -> {{0.20, 0.27}, {0, 1.05}}, 
   ImageSize -> 500, Frame -> {{False, False}, {True, False}}, 
   Ticks -> {{0.22, 0.25}, Automatic}];

plot03 = ListPlot[{data01, data02, data03, data04, fitdata}, 
   Joined -> {False, False, False, False, True}, PlotStyle -> Black, 
   PlotMarkers -> {"+", "-", Text[x], "\[FilledSquare]", ""}, 
   AspectRatio -> Full, PlotRange -> {{0.38, 0.48}, {0, 1.05}}, 
   ImageSize -> 500, Frame -> {{False, False}, {True, False}}, 
   Ticks -> {{0.40, 0.45}, Automatic}];

plotGrid[{{plot01, plot02, plot03}}, ImageSize -> 500, 
 "MergeAxes" -> "Cut", Spacings -> {10, 10}, 
 ItemSize -> {{1, 0.25, 0.25}}, "HideOuterTickLabels" -> {All}]
```

[image]

Comment: @kglr Do you think you are able to help? You helped me with my last post kind of similar to this?